# how to use setTimeout useState in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, settimeout

I want to have a div, when you click it, the text will change for a few sec. but with ts there is an error.**`Line 22:7 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`**

my Code:

```js
  const [showCopy, setShowCopy] = useState(false);


  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowCopy(true);
    setTimeout(() => {        // <- this is Line 22:7 | error
      setShowCopy(false), 2000;
    });
  };
```

my JSX:

```js
 <div  onClick={() => {
            navigator.clipboard.writeText("1234");
            handleClick();
          }}
>
            {showCopy ? (
              "you copyed the no."
            ) : (
             "1234"
            )}
/div>
```

Comment: Your `2000` is not at the right place. `setTimeout(func, timer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add time as a second argument in setTimeout

```
setTimeout(() => {        
  setShowCopy(false);
}, 2000);
```